# Code Signing: Available profiles are different from Project and Target screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing

I had to change my bundle identifier to have access to the correct provisioning profiles to build my project for the store. To do this I changed the project plist (`bundle identifier` and `bundle versions string, short`) and also changed the same fields in the summary tab of my projects "target".

When I click project -> build settings -> code signing I see all of the correct profiles for the new bundle identifier.

When I click targets -> build settings -> code signing I see all of the old profiles for the old bundle identifier.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? Project should enable all profiles, and target should enable the profiles you can use.

Comment: I suppose that's correct. I just want to have access to the correct profiles in the target after changing the bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting the provisioning profiles you need to cross check the following things,

```
1. is your certificate valid for your provisioning profile?

2. is bundle identifier of provisioning profile and info.plist are same?

3. is the compiler settings for project and targets are same?

4. is deployment target is valid?
```

Please check all the above cases. if these all are fine, the problem is something different. let me know whether these are perfect or not?

Comment: thanks a lot, I followed this list and discovered I had a duplicate certificate...basically I deleted all of my expired profiles, and all expired certificates and all duplicates and it works again.